# Python multiprocessing: Kill worker on exit

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have written a simple function to run jobs with dependency tracking. The exact code isn't important, but the way I did it is to create a job monitoring function that I fork with `multiprocessing.Process`, I send and get jobs to/from it with two multiprocessing `Queue` objects.

It works great, but because I use an infinite loop, when the parent process hangs on exit, because python is still waiting for the child. Is there a good way to kill a child process immediately on exit? Maybe by catching a signal?

My actual code is here:
https://gist.github.com/MikeDacre/e672969aff980ee950b9dfa8b2552d40
A more complete example is here:
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/MikeDacre/python-cluster/blob/cluster/tests/local_queue.ipynb

A toy example is probably better though:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep
def runner():
    while True:
        sleep(2)

runner = mp.Process(target=runner)
runner.start()
exit()
```

That will happily hang until Ctrl-C is entered.

I don't think signal catching will work, as there are no signals sent on normal exit. Is there any way to catch `exit()`? If not is there any way to create a Process in a way that will terminate naturally?

Comment: You could check for the parent pid in EnumProcesses instead of `while True`.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I don't know how to use EnumProcesses, is that part of multiprocessing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone, shortly after writing this question, I figured out the solution using python's `atexit` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html):

```
import atexit
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep
def runner():
    while True:
        sleep(2)

def kill_runner(runner):
    runner.terminate()

runner = mp.Process(target=runner)
runner.start()
atexit.register(kill_runner, runner)
exit()
```

That works as expected.